# Somehow physically colliding with Collision Triggers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

With a whole bunch of copy-pasting from all over the web, I managed to hack together a piece of C# code which spawns a random object from an array when the player enters a large, spherical collision trigger. When the player leaves the trigger, the object is deleted. It's working almost as intended, only problem is that  six out of ten times when the player passes through the collider, for a split second it feels like a physical collider. Meaning that although the player is trying to move straight forward, he or she will move left or right along the trigger collider for about half a second, before the object spawns and the player can move freely again.

I was under the impression that checking the "Is Trigger" box would remove all physical properties of that specific collider? Am I missing something?
I'm using the standard FPS Character Controller in Unity 5 if that might have something to do with it.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized my solution didn't get posted as I thought it had. Yoyo's solution was correct. The object containing the code was also the trigger. Switched so that the player was the trigger and now all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the spherical collision trigger has a rigid body component, and that the "Is Kinematic" property of the rigid body is checked.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried adding a rigid body component, and when pressing the play button, unity freezes. It's happened three times now. Very confusing. Also, right before it freezes, I can see the objects appearing even though the player is well away from the trigger boundary. Is unity getting confused by the fact that a huge rigidbody is spawning embedded into a plane?

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Are you using OnTriggerEnter / OnTriggerExit methods for handling the collision?

Comment: Tried disabling the mesh collider for the plane and although I fell through the map - it didn't freeze. So I figured, maybe the problem is that the rigidbody is clipping with the terrain? I made a box collider instead that wasn't touching the ground plane, and when the player passed through it, the object spawned and then unity stuttered and froze again. EDIT: Yep, I am.

Comment: Sorry, without more information about your project it's hard to say. Try removing things until it works, then adding pieces back bit by bit until the problem happens again.

Comment: I think I know what the basic issue is, but not what is causing it. I think that somehow the game thinks the player is entering the trigger EVERY FRAME. Last time I tried adding a rigidbody, I decided not to make it kinematic. Before unity froze again, I could see it spawning the object what was probably hundreds of times downwards in the y-axis.

Comment: Did you implement OnTriggerEnter in the player or in  the trigger volume? Might be helpful to add some of your OnTriggerEnter code to the question, and some notes on your scene / object / component layout.